# Link to app in Google play

Tags: android, android-intent

I have prepared a lite version of an App. I would like to take the user to the paid version in Google play if user clicks on "Buy Option". Could you please point me the process/steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Intent and start activity like in [this](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#android-app) example.

Comment: Regarding the intent, do I need to add something in manifest file

Comment: internet permissiens and thats all

Comment: Shouldn't need even the internet permission. You're not using the internet directly, but delegating it to Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

Your package name is app name in play store , so manually you can create the link like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=**Your Paid's App Package Name**"));
startActivity(intent);
```

And add this to your button's event.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
final String appName = "com.example.yourapp"; //name of your package here
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appName)));
```

Let me know if you have any more questions